# Are LHCP L-Band antennas for Cubesats available?

Tags: cubesat, antenna, gps, gnss

I am designing a cubesat to carry out [GNSS reflectometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNSS_reflectometry) or GNSS-R. To collect the earth reflected signals, I need a nadir pointing array of patch antennas, with Left Hand Circular Polarisation (LHCP) and operating in L1 and L2 bands.

Does anyone know if these can be sourced off-the-shelf, or are these custom build? Would it be possible to modify a readily available RHCP antenna into a LHCP antenna, and increase the frequency that it operates at? Appreciate any help.

Comment: There's some interesting results of hand-modifying L-band patch antennas to reverse the polarity at this link (https://www.satelliteguys.us/xen/threads/experimenting-with-l-band-antennas.363533/).  My first reaction is "wow, the original hardware had really low circularity if you get that much "opposite pol" through even before making alterations, but my second reaction is perhaps that my experience is with antennas so far from that price scale that I probably shouldn't expect what I see at work anywhere near someone's home.  :)

Comment: I have used Antcom antennas with LHCP polarization. I can't find them in their web (https://antcom.com/) so maybe they were specially designed for us at that time. I believe they can do it again.

Besides GNSS-R, LHCP antennas are also used in sophisticated multipath mitigation strategies, so you may try to find something for this.